# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException near "CREATE TABLE peopleTable ":syntax error (code1)

Tags: android

I am making a simple database application.

I got an error while compiling: `CREATE TABLE peopleTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, persons_name TEXT NOT NULL persons_hotness TEXT NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a **necessary** comma before the last column:

```
 CREATE TABLE peopleTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, persons_name TEXT NOT NULL persons_hotness TEXT NOT NULL);
```

it has to be:

```
 CREATE TABLE peopleTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, persons_name TEXT NOT NULL, persons_hotness TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: this is my table 

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE  + "(" + 

     KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
     KEY_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL , " + 
     KEY_HOTNESS + "TEXT NOT NULL);" );
  }

Comment: This SQL statement won't work, because it's missing a **necessary** space after the `CREATE TABLE` statement, a space before `INTEGER`, and a space before `TEXT` (twice). Please change it so to read: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL)" );`